# .NET Open Source Contour Plotting

Tags: .net, plot, eps, zedgraph, contour

I am looking for an Open Source .NET Library (or wrapper to a library) that will create contour plots from a set of values along a grid/mesh.  ZedGraph is the closest thing I could find (http://zedgraph.org/).

It would also be great if it could export to EPS.

Comment: You probably should be able to do it with ZedGraph. 
Also, it provides the functionality to save in EPS. There were also few topics here on SO regarding using ZG to save in real EPS format.

Comment: Thanks, its great to know it has the ability to write to EPS.  That being true I may add the functionality to ZedGraph.  They provide an example of a contour plot, but frankly I don't consider that real contour functionality.  I need an efficient contour plot given a mesh.  I just need a good algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

[With D3 you can plot contour lines (isolines) for WPF](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/). I am not sure about contour surfaces. WPF has great printing capabilities so I think that printing to EPS would not be a problem.

**Edit:** recently found [this](http://www.esnips.com/doc/3403c875-a957-43b0-a134-8f693d8a4b98/wContourDemo_2011_7_28) one WinForms example around a .dll which calculates isolines.

Comment: I couldn't find a feature list, but it appears to be able to

Comment: post have dead links

Answer (score 2):

The contour extraction routine ConRec worked very well (fast and efficient) for me:

http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/

It doesn't output contours but a collection of line segments and associated z-values.  You can use this raw data to construct contour polygon if required.

Comment: wow, simplest lib same like your simplest explanation.