# Contour Lines Algorithm

Tags: vb6, grid, contour

This could very well be a duplicate, but I could not seem to find something specific to my problem.

I have a xy grid in a picture box. Each grid cell has a specific mass. I would like to create contour lines on this xy grid based on the mass.

Does anyone have any ideas to a good algorithm to perform this task? I am trying to get this done in VB6 but any algorithm would do.

**Edit**

[Contour Grid](http://dennisglasberg.com/contour%20Grid.png)

I have a grid. I want to display contour lines based on mass (IE, the cells with more than one point in them will be heavier in mass)

Comment: Perhaps if you could provide an example of the result you would like to see, you would have a better response.

Comment: http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/ : Someone mentioned this on another question : http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3180401/net-open-source-contour-plotting

Answer (score 1):

This question's a bit stale, but so's my experience: I did something like this almost 30 years ago.

This produces simple contours on a bitmap:

- Calculate the field-strength at each point in the grid (I'm assuming you're trying to plot something like gravitational field contours based on the masses of the points).
- Colour the alternate spaces between contour lines (which you haven't got yet) in two alternate colours.  e.g. if the contour lines should be 100 units (of field-strength) apart then choose the colour of each pixel based on `ToInt(pixel_field_strength / 100) % 2`.
- Trace the edges of the colour boundaries to produce contours.  For example, if your two colours are white and black, then only retain white pixels adjacent to a black pixel.

If you're just interested in the results, use a library as suggested in the comments.

Purely for nostalgia's sake, I found my original BBC BASIC code.  It still runs on modelb (a BBC Micro emulator).

```
   10 REM THIS COMES WITH NO WARRANTY!
   20  
   30 REM Gravity field
   40  
   50 MODE 1
   60 PROCsetup
   70 FOR Y%=300 TO 900 STEP 4
   80   FOR X%=200 TO 800 STEP 4
   90     R=LOG(FNforce(X%,Y%))
  100     GCOL0,((R*10) MOD 2)+1
  110     PLOT69,X%,Y%
  120     NEXT
  130   NEXT
  140 PROCcontour
  150 VDU19,1,0,0,0,0
  160 VDU19,2,0,0,0,0
  170 END
  180 DEFPROCsetup
  190 N%=5
  200 DIM X%(N%),Y%(N%),M%(N%)
  210 FOR P%=1 TO N%
  220   READ X%(P%),Y%(P%),M%(P%)
  230   NEXT
  240 ENDPROC
  250 DATA 625,625,1000000
  260 DATA 425,725,1000000
  270 DATA 475,425,1000000
  280 DATA 375,575,1000000
  290 DATA 725,525,1000000
  300 DEFFNforce(X,Y)
  310 P=0
  320 FOR P%=1 TO N%
  330   DX=X%(P%)-X:DY=Y%(P%)-Y
  340   R=SQR(DX*DX+DY*DY)
  350   P=P+M%(P%)/R
  360   NEXT
  370 =P
  380 DEFPROCcontour
  390 GCOL0,3
  400 FOR Y%=300 TO 900 STEP 4
  410   FOR X%=200 TO 800 STEP 4
  420     IF POINT(X%,Y%)=1 AND (POINT(X%+4,Y%)=2 OR POINT(X%-4,Y%)=2 OR POINT(X%,Y%+4)=2 OR POINT(X%,Y%-4)=2) THEN PLOT69,X%,Y% 
  430     NEXT
  440   NEXT
  450 ENDPROC
```